# Solidity: Is there a way to get VSCode Intellisense for imported contracts?

Tags: visual-studio-code, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, openzeppelin

I'm a Solidity newbie getting his feet wet. I am following along with a YouTube ERC721 tutorial. The tutorial has me calling functions imported from "@openzeppelin".

I was wondering if there is a way to get intellisense to show the interface of these functions on hover. I have the Solidity extension installed and thought that would help but apparently not.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm looking for the same thing

Answer (score 1):

If you've properly imported the @openzeppelin contract, then the function/contract interface should be visible on hover + CMD click. See this screenshot:

[image: Click CMD on hovering over function/contract]